# Cypress Test-Runner: Hide detailed messages, instead of being expanded?

Tags: integration-testing, cypress

A default behaviour of the Cypress Test-Runner is that the messages-list on the left-panel is expanded. So the detailed messages are shown.

As shown here:

[image: Default behaviour]

One can collapse and hide the messages by clicking the triangle-button.

It then looks that way:

[image: Collapsed]

**Is there a way to reverse the default behaviour?**

So that the messages-list is hidden by default and one has to click the triangle to expand the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today(v5.3.0), Cypress doesn't provide an option to keep the test runner messages in an opened state or a closed state by default. You can refer the below Github links for more info -

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6270

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7820